# Running into issues just typing

Tags: navigation, typing-break

I'll be typing and for no reason my cursor will automatically move somewhere else on the page or paragraph and for the lack of a better phrase "jack my shit up".

It happens when I either press the Shift or Enter key. More noticeable with the Shift Key.

Comment: What kind of keyboard are you using? USB? Bluetooth? What happens if you use a different keyboard?

Comment: Are you using a laptop? if yes, have you tried disabling the touchpad?

Comment: I'm running an Ubuntu partition on my Mac so it's the built-in keyboard. I'll give it a reboot and try again. Disabling it can't be done since I require it for navigation on the websites. Thanks for the quick replies.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on which mac you're using, since you said its a built in keyboard im assuming it might be a macbook, you could try installing these drivers:

https://github.com/Dunedan/mbp-2016-linux

Im running ubuntu 17.10 on a 2017 macbook pro, and the keyboard/touchpad both didnt work at all until I went and installed these, now they work like a charm. They should fix little bugs like you're having as well.

I believe there are also drivers for older laptops linked in that thread